# Mysql php select Columns after selecting from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need help with a thing regarding mysql and php.

I have the following dropdown:

```
    <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And a database with all car models.

I need to echo a SELECT from my database based on the value selected from the dropdown.

So if the user in the website selects Volvo he will recieve selection from my mysql database with the following info:

```
Volvo S30
Volvo S60
Volvo S90
etc.
```

**EDIT**

The select would be :

SELECT Imagename, Imageurl FROM pics WHERE Carmaker=Volvo

But i don`t know how to make the SELECT be conditioned by the users selected option.

Comment: Sure. You post the selected value to your server side, read the posted value and construct your select query. There are millions of examples for such things to be found here on SO and on google.

Comment: I`m a beginner and I don`t know what to search to create such an example. Please help me with some links or something.

Comment: Search for things like "php tutorial form select post". This would be an example: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give you a quick help.

First you have to set the name attribute at html select.

```
<select name="type">
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Then in the file that form redirects you:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
$car_type = (int)$_POST['type'];    //Code for user input validation and sanitization
$query = "SELECT Imagename, Imageurl FROM pics WHERE Carmaker = '$car_type';";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}

//Then you can make a loop to take the data one by one

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<p>'.$row['Imagename'].' '.$row['Imageurl'].'</p>';
}
```

For start try to use queries using mysqli_* functions (not mysql_*). Then try to learn PDO or something similar. Also it is very important to read some tutorials explaining server side user input validation and sanitization.